# libgdx AssetManager preload ttf font not working

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I have this code executed when application starts

```
val resolver = InternalFileHandleResolver()
asset.setLoader(FreeTypeFontGenerator::class.java, FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader(resolver))
asset.setLoader(BitmapFont::class.java, ".ttf", FreetypeFontLoader(resolver))

val menuFont = FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter()
menuFont.fontFileName = FONT_FN
menuFont.fontParameters.size = 10
asset.load(FONT_MENU, BitmapFont::class.java, menuFont)

val gameFont = FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter()
gameFont.fontFileName = FONT_FN
gameFont.fontParameters.size = 15
asset.load(FONT_GAME, BitmapFont::class.java, gameFont)

asset.finishLoading()
```

the `asset` is my `AssetManager`, and the constants are:

```
const val FONT_FN = "others/font.ttf"
const val FONT_MENU = "FONT_MENU"
const val FONT_GAME = "FONT_GAME"
```

Now I have these helper functions:

```
private fun addLabel(text: String, x: Float, y: Float, font: BitmapFont, color: Color, stage: Stage): Label {
    val label = Label(text, Label.LabelStyle(font, color))
    label.setPosition(x, y)
    stage.addActor(label)
    return label
}

fun addLabelForMenu(text: String, x: Float, y: Float, stage: Stage): Label {
     val font = asset.get(FONT_MENU, BitmapFont::class.java)
     val color = Color.WHITE
     return addLabel(text, x, y, font, color, stage)
}

fun addLabelForGame(text: String, x: Float, y: Float, stage: Stage): Label {
     val font = asset.get(FONT_GAME, BitmapFont::class.java)
     val color = Color.WHITE
     return addLabel(text, x, y, font, color, stage)
}
```

The game crashes when calling `addLabelForMenu`:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: others/font.ttf
```

I am following the wiki page here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const val FONT_FN = "others/font.ttf"    // Make sure your `font.ttf` file is inside `others` folder
```

Add `.ttf` extension to fileName that you're using to load and retrieve.

so change

```
const val FONT_MENU = "FONT_MENU"
const val FONT_GAME = "FONT_GAME"
```

to

```
const val FONT_MENU = "FONT_MENU.ttf"
const val FONT_GAME = "FONT_GAME.ttf"
```